# PHP simple singleton don't work

Tags: php

I am trying to make a `singleton pattern` but it seems I am making mistake somewhere. Everytime i try to create an instance from the class `Cart` it makes new one. Tested it with the `setId()` and `getId()` functions. It returns different number everytime.

```
class Cart
{
    private $cartQuantity = 0;

    private static $instance;

    private $id;

    private function __construct(){}

    public function addQuantity($quantity){
        $this->cartQuantity += $quantity;
    }

    public function getQuantity(){
        return $this->cartQuantity;
    }

    public function setId(){
        $this->id = rand(0, 10);
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public static function startCount(){
        if(self::$instance === null){
            self::$instance = new Cart();
            self::$instance->setId();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}

$inst = Cart::startCount();
echo $inst->getId();
```

What am I doing wrong? Seems like legit block of code to me :/ Thank you in advance!

Comment: "What am I doing wrong" - I think, testing. https://3v4l.org/V9Y9b
The code successfully returns same id.

Comment: yes, works for me as well

Comment: Hm. OK! Thank you very much! Guess the problem is somewhere else. Will keep searching for it :)

Comment: Since you are making card. I'm guessing you expect the singleton to keep is data between each requests? Maybe you're looking for [session](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php). -- [The Singleton will only live for the current request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633229/singleton-pattern-in-php-how-can-i-save-state-between-requests).

Answer (score 0):

Your singleton is working perfectly. I have tested it 10 times with the following code:

```
$inst = Cart::startCount();
echo $inst->getId();

$winst = Cart::startCount();
echo $inst->getId();

$ninst = Cart::startCount();
echo $ninst->getId();

$ninst->setId();
echo $ninst->getId();
echo $winst->getId();

$ginst = Cart::startCount();
echo $ginst->getId();
```

Results:

```
999444
555222
333999
333444
111111
222222
999999
888666
101010999
000777
```

If you change the ID, it keeps beeing changed. Otherwise always the same is returned. This is exactly what you should expect (note that `rand(0,10)`) also can deliver 10.

There is **never more than one instance**.